# Tensorflow Dataset giving incompatible shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I made a test dataset out of a larger one to just run a preliminary check, and i'm out of ideas.
The problem is that it is correctly formatted for training (the input is (4096,5,1), as with the input of the model).

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((copy1[1].tolist(), copy1[0].tolist()))
x = data.as_numpy_iterator().next()
(x[0].shape, x[1]) #to check whether its correct or not
```

as expected, `x[0].shape` gives out (4096,5,1) and `x[1]` gives out a list (one hot encoded value)

and when i load it into the model through
`model.fit(data)` method, it throws in the following error

**ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_2: expected shape=(None, 4096, 5, 1), found shape=(4096, 5, 1)**

can someone help me with this idea so that I can proceed further?

Comment: Hi @Zephyr0112, By adding dimension to the data using `tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0) `will not produce the error. Thank you!